# JavaScript (or jQuery) to do math within a form before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an expense report type form that has an input asking for mileage. When a user types in a number, I'd like there to be an auto calculate sort of function that displays the amount they will be reimbursed.

For instance, if a user types in "65", to the right of the input box would be "65 x $.555 = $36.08".

JS is not my strong suit, but I know I'll need to use a hidden div to display the JS generated text, and some code to make sure the "total" is rounded to 2 decimal places. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Sounds totally feasible. You are looking for use to code it for you?

Comment: use $('selector').change() event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/c4xwP/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#amount').change(function () {
         var $this = $(this);

        $this.next('label').text((parseFloat($this.val()) * .555).toFixed(2))            
    });        
});​
```

jQuery isn't needed, but helpful.

[**toFixed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method

[**parseFloat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) method

---

If you needed to do the rounding:

```
var rounded = Math.round(parseFloat($this.val()) * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your form tag, add an `onsubmit` attribute that calls the math function. For example :

```
<form action="movie.php" method="post" onsubmit="doTheMath()">
```

And then create the function with Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doTheMath() 
{
     // do something

     // submit the form
     return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Inline events are a bad idea.

Comment: thats only half a solution, and inline event handlers can be looked at as bad practice...its obtrusive..you should use event handlers from js or jquery

Comment: I would be perfectly happy not displaying it as soon as they type it in, however my "clients" (coworkers) want to see the amount. I'm pretty certain I can't do a form within a form, so this was my next "best" solution. If I wanted to collect the input on this page and calculate on another I'd do it in PHP (which is how the rest of the form is displayed).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

HTML:

```
​<form method="post">
<span>Type here:</span><input type="text" id="num"></input>
</form>

<span id="display_text"></span>
```

JS:

```
num_field = document.getElementById("num");
num_field.onkeyup=function () {

    mult_field = 0.555;
    num_math = num_field.value * mult_field;
    num_string = num_field.value + "*" + mult_field + "=" + num_math;
    document.getElementById("display_text").innerHTML = num_string;
}​
```

This will do the math and display it while you type.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9jcC/

Comment: To add the rounding just change one line: `num_math = Math.round(num_field.value * mult_field);`

Answer (score 1):

Using plain javascript

```
window.onload=function()
{
    var txt=document.getElementById('amount');
    var span=document.createElement('span');
    txt.parentNode.insertBefore(span, txt.nextSibling);
    txt.onkeyup=function()
    {
        span.innerHTML="";
        var val=txt.value;
        if(val.length > 0 && isNaN(val)) 
        {
            span.innerHTML=" Invalid number !";
            return false;
        }
        var result=val*0.555;
        if(parseFloat(result)>0) span.innerHTML=' $'+result.toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9VMZu/3/)